# React Redux could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

Am getting an error while running npm test, **could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider**

My App.test.js

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

My index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import store from "./redux/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

I have wrapped App component with Provider, but still am getting an error while running test.

This is my App component :

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import MoviesList from './pages/MoviesList';
import MovieDetails from './pages/MovieDetails';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/MoviesList" element={<MoviesList />} />
          <Route path="/MovieDetails/:movieId" element={<MovieDetails />} />
          <Route path="/*" element={<MoviesList />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I try to use useDispatch am getting an error
[image]
MovieList.js :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { loadMovies, searchMovie } from '../redux/actions';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Search from './Search';
import Loading from './Loading';
import '../movie.css';

const MovieList = () => {
    let [search, setSearch] = useState(false)
    let dispach = useDispatch();
    let movieList = useSelector(state => state.data);
    let fetching = useSelector(state => state.data.fetching);    
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispach(loadMovies());
    }, [])
```

These are the dependencies I have added :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Comment: When you render the component in your test, you will have to wrap it with Provider for it to have access to useDispatch. Also, probably with Router as you need useNavigate as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your component with the redux provider and `<MemoryRouter/>` from react-router-dom library inside your test case.

```
...
<Provider store={mockedStore}>
 <MemoryRouter>
   <TestedComponent />
 </MemoryRouter>
<Provider>
...
```

More details about testing connected components you can find here https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#connected-components